# Overlay div no longer fills screen after the screen height has changed

Tags: jquery, css

I've got an overlay div that I use for when Ajax requests are loading.  The CSS for the div is roughly this:

```
#ajax-overlay {
    z-index:9999;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

I use the basic jQuery to show it:

```
$('#ajax-overlay').show();
```

The problem is things are changing dynamically on my page with JavaScript, so the height of the page changes, after which the overlay no longer fills the screen.

What can I add to the JS to force the overlay to resize every time to the correct size?

Comment: is there a possibility to us `position: relative` on `<body>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you use width and height 100%? Those values are too buggy on IE. Use just the fixed values:

```
#ajax-overlay {
   z-index:9999;
   display:none;
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   background:#000;
   opacity:0.8;
}
```

With this code you will get the `ajax-overlay` `div` filling the screen no matter what happens on the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Change your position to 'fixed'

Answer (score 0):

One either do it by position
**e.g.**

```
#ajax-overlay {
    z-index:9999;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

**or**

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var h = $(window).height();
        var w = $(window).width();
        $('#ajax-overlay').css("width",w).css("height",h);
    });
});
```